# get finish_reason in llama_index

Tags: python, openai-api, large-language-model, llama-index

how can i get the **finish_reason** of the OpenAI response with llama_index? 
this is an example of my code:

```
query_engine = index.as_query_engine()
response = query_engine.query("what is this document about?")
```

I need to get the finish_reason as in the OpenAI response

```
{
  "choices": [
    {
      "finish_reason": "stop",
      "index": 0,
      "message": {
        "content": "This document is about molecular biology",
        "role": "assistant"
      }
    }
  ],
  "created": xxx,
  "id": "xxx",
  "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo-0301",
  "object": "chat.completion",
  "usage": {
    "completion_tokens": 301,
    "prompt_tokens": 36,
    "total_tokens": 337
  }
}
```